# Postgresql is it possible to create index on unstructured json using expression index

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

I'm having a little problem, trying to optimize querying data from an unstructured JSON column.

By unstructured I mean, each json column is unique on each row.

By using this query, I want to collect all the keys which are matching the prefix:

```sql
select j.key as value
from tasks t, lateral jsonb_each_text(t.tags) j
where j.key ilike '%some_key%'
group by j.key
order by j.key;
```

but on loaded table these queries take up to 20k milliseconds to execute.

I found an index which can work with `ilike` statements (`trgm_idx`)
but how to put it here, still have no clue.

Please great Postgres masters, help me if you have any ideas

PS: small update, if you know how to make it even faster if I use

```sql
select j.key as value
from tasks t, lateral jsonb_each_text(t.tags) j
where j.key ilike 'some_prefix%'
group by j.key
order by j.key;
```

I can work around it

Comment: It is easy to find certain attributes in a JSON column using a GIN index, but you won't be able to use pattern matching or prefix matching for JSON attributes using an index.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor design, you should probably rethink it.  But it is possible.  You would need to create a helper function which returns all keys munged into one string, picking a suitable delimiter which is not going to show up in either keys or in patterns:

```
create function all_keys(jsonb) returns text language sql immutable as $$
   select string_agg(key,'===') from jsonb_each_text($1);  
$$;

create index on tasks using gin (all_keys(tags) gin_trgm_ops);

select * from tasks where all_keys(tags) ilike '%some_key%';
```

This query will return each task at most once, unlike your original query, so may need some tweaking to make it do exactly what you want.  Maybe (untested):

```
select j.key as value
from tasks t, lateral jsonb_each_text(t.tags) j
where all_keys(t.tags) ilike '%some_key%'
and j.key ilike '%some_key%'
group by j.key
order by j.key;
```

The first ilike should provide performance assuming few tasks have any qualifying keys (nor many false positives).  The 2nd one produces just the specific keys which match, including multiplicity of them.

Comment: thanks for the help, but how do you think, if i use and j.key ilike 'some_key%' do you know faster solution?

Comment: That should work fine if the all_keys comparison used a % on both beginning and end, while the j.key pattern used it only on the end.  I can't think of a way to get faster than that, without writing an extension with a lot of custom C code.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the use of `jsonb_each_text()`, you're actually dealing with `jsonb` rather than plain `json`, so `jsonpath` functions are available to you without having map to `text`

In PostgreSQL [JSONPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) there's a [`like_regex`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS) [filter expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-FILTER-EX-TABLE) you can use with the match operator [`@?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). Sadly, even though that match operator is supported by `jsonb_ops` as well as `jsonb_path_ops` operator classes

> The default GIN operator class for `jsonb` supports queries with the key-exists operators `?`, `?|` and `?&`, the containment operator @>, and the `jsonpath` match operators **`@?`** and `@@`.

searching key names requires [`.keyvalue().key`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE) accessor that [won't work with that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). Still, you might gain some performance due to the mere fact you're not deconstructing your `jsonb`'s, casting to text, then matching against that, but rather interact with them directly, through a purpose-built function: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1aU70bO5)

```sql
select jsonb_path_query(tags,'$.keyvalue().key?(@ like_regex ".*some_key.*")')
from tasks t
where tags @? '$.keyvalue().key?(@ like_regex ".*some_key.*")'
group by 1 
order by 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but how do you think, if i use and j.key ilike 'some_key%' do you know faster solution?